# Is there a way to convert img to grayscale with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to convert an image into grayscale using python and cv2. I saw a few other answers and they were using matlab, which I am not going to use. Is there anyway that I can fix this issue. The image boots up fine and everything it just wont convert. Here is the code.

```
import cv2

# Choose an image to detect faces in
img = cv2.imread('RDJ.png')

# Must convert to grayscale
grayscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


#
cv2.imshow('Face Detector', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I have tried to fix it using different things but I cant figure out any solutions.

Comment: i could write you a solution in Pillow, or PIL which you can then use with opencv if that would fit your workflow :)

Comment: Yeah, I am a beginner programmer so I don't really know what that means but if it will work then ill give it a try! :)

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. your question was closed because it's basically a typo and you didn't debug your code before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the penultimate line of your code:

```
cv2.imshow('Face Detector', grayscaled_img)
```

Because the image showed is the original.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have considered the image wasn't converted because it wasn't showed; the image was effectively converted and stored in the *grayscaled_img* variable. If it wasn't what you have considered, please explain your thinking.

Comment: No that is exactly what it was. I tried that and it worked immediately. Thanks so much!!!